# Credentials: 'include' not including Cookie header

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api

I'm using `credentials: 'include'` and `mode: 'cors'` on the client. On the server I see `access-control-allow-credentials: true` and `access-control-allow-origin: https://dev.com:9443` headers. I don't see my `cookie` header though and I can't seem to find why it isn't sending. Let me know if I can provide any further details.

Fetch request

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'get',
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Options Request Headers

```
:authority: prod.fakedomain.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /Search
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers: content-type
access-control-request-method: GET
cache-control: no-cache
dnt: 1
origin: https://dev.com:9443
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://dev.com:9443/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Options Response Headers

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,POST
access-control-allow-origin: https://dev.com:9443
access-control-max-age: 1800
allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 03:45:06 GMT
status: 200
vary: Origin
x-application-context: application:8080
```

Get Request Headers

```
:authority: prod.fakedomain.com
:method: GET
:path: /Search
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json
dnt: 1
origin: https://dev.com:9443
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://dev.com:9443/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Get Response Headers

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://dev.com:9443
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 03:45:07 GMT
status: 200
vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
x-application-context: application:8080
```

Comment: it looks like your server don't send back cookies - how do you check that server send cookies?

Comment: It's not that the server should be sending me cookies. I want to send the server the client's cookies. The server wants to looks at the client's cookies and send a personalized response based on them. Currently it doesn't see the client cookies and just sends a generic non-personalized response back.

Comment: The information in the question seems to indicate your browser doesn’t actually have a cookie set yet in its cookie store for the `prod.fakedomain.com` domain. The only cookies your browser will send back to `prod.fakedomain.com` are the cookies for that domain which have already been set in your browser’s cookie store by some previous response from `prod.fakedomain.com` which included a Set-Cookie response header. And as @KamilKiełczewski indicated, that server doesn’t seem to be sending back any Set-Cookie header, so it seems like you’re never getting cookies set in the browser to begin with

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks! So I have cookies set for `dev.com` but not `prod.fakedomain.com`. I want the server(`prod.fakedomain.com`) to see my `dev.com` cookies. Will those not be sent if there are not the `prod.fakedomain.com` domain?

Comment: @anthony-dandrea if cookies from dev.com are NOT httpOnly then you can try to copy cookies (read and write) by JS

Comment: Thanks everyone. Appears my issue is with the domain the cookies I want to send are set to. If either of you want to post an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) mention in his comment, the browser don't set te cookie for domain `prod.fakedomain.com` and its look like that server don't set cookie too. So if you set cookies for `dev.com` and they are not httpOnly then you can try to copy them to `prod.fakedomain.com` (by read and write it by JS).

If you want to store sensitive data in the cookies (e.g. JWT token), read about XSS/XST attacks and consider the possibility of using the HttpOnly flag.

Answer (score 11):

I finally find out that problem just browser not allow two not same domain share any cookie(except for the same second level domain), it's beyond `credentials: include` can do, after 2 hours trying... I find out `credentials: include`  just meaning u can send cookie but it doesn't meaning you can send cookie with two different domain..

Whatever you do, change browser setting、set cookie's `SameSite` any way, just can't do that...

So that is my conclusion，hope u get it...

Comment: Sadly, I believe this is true nowadays. There are old links/resources (including the MDN fetch documentation) pointing to  using a combination of SameSite=None + Allow Credentials header + fetch 'include' option. None seems to be working

Comment: Have you got a source for what you claim here?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this issue by going into my Safari privacy settings and unchecking `Prevent cross-site tracking`

[image]

Comment: wow this worked! How to do the same from chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried for days then come into conclusion:

```
cedentials: 'include'
```

and

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true}
```

Only works on **same domain** with different port, if we want to make request to another domain we have to manually add credentials (token etc..) to the request header

Comment: Have you got a source saying such?